# Scapy and sys.argv issue

Tags: python, scapy

I am puzzling with scapy and sys.arg, i.e. when importing scapy also sys.arg is available

I am running a very simple script tester.py :

```
print(sys.argv[0])
print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[2])
```

which with command python3 tester.py qwe 123
delivers:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tester.py", line 3, in 
print(sys.argv[0])
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
That is expectable

But when I run:

```
from scapy.all import *

print(sys.argv[0])
print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[2])
```

everything works as expected:

python3 tester.py qwe 123
tester.py
qwe
123

Does it mean that scapy contains sys library?

Comment: use import scapy.all as scapy,  i don't think Scapy d contain the sys library, but it imports it internally.  In Python, when you import a module that itself imports another module, the second module becomes available in the namespace of the first. So when you do from scapy.all import *, you're also importing everything that Scapy imports, including sys